# svn status wc. What does this flag do?

Tags: svn, command-line-interface

After checking out a repository, i've got a 'tree conflict', which was resolved. I've done `svn revert` and `svn update` several times. Anyway, now i have folders that exist in repository (visible in browser via http), but not exist locally.

Now - `svn status` is showing them as `D` (marked for deletion)

but `svn status wc` ("working copy") gives empty list of changes.

I've done `svn revert` and `svn update` several times, again, but it does not change the output.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html

So, no idea what's happening here - my working copy is up to date, but the server still has cached version of files - or server is ok, but my local svn went broke. Which leads to the  question:

1. What is the `wc` flag doing?
2. What info is `svn status` showing, when you don't specify it?
3. Is it the same as `-u` flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SVNBook examples `svn status wc` reads `svn status /path/to/workingcopy`. In other words `wc` is not a command-line argument or a flag, it's path to the working copy.

So the answers are:

1. `wc` does nothing. It's used in SVNBook's examples as `/path/to/workingcopy`,
2. `svn status` without any arguments runs against the directory where the terminal points to. E.g. it's the same as `svn status .`
3. No, it isn't. `-u` flag shows changes that exist on the remote repository but not in your local working copy.

I advise you to checkout a clean working copy and compare it with the existing one. The one you have right now may have some local modifications (e.g. `D` (deletes) after locally-resolved tree conflict).